# mayim emtzaiyim - washing hands between eating fish and meat

Tags: meat, netilat-yadayim-washing, fish, meal-seudah

*Mishna B'rura* 173:4 and *Aruch Hashulchan* 173:2 say we don't need to wash our hands between eating fish and eating meat. Do any latter-day *pos'kim* argue with this? Does any group practice this *halacha* of washing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that R. Ovadia Yossef says it's good to do Mayim Emtsaiyim even if some poskim say it's not necessary since we use spoon, knife...

You can see in Yalqut Yossef (Kitsur Shulhan Arouch) hilchot Seouda. (For the end of your question, I practice this halacha)